# Powershell: saving xml changes in a new xml variable or object, keeping the original object unchanged

Tags: xml, powershell, variables, object, updates

I have a xml variable that I get from `Invoke-restmethod`. Lets call it `$object1`

I want to make a new variable or object `$object2` that is the same as `$object1`  but with a few changes to the values

Here is what I have tried:

```
$object2 = $object1

$object2.sweets.candy.Where({$_.lemondrop -gt 1}) | Foreach{$_.gumdrop = 20}
```

Now the problem with that is when I double check `$object1` the value is changed there too... I dont want that

I just want the chage to remain in `$object2`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *clone* `$object1` in order to obtain an independent copy of it:

```sh
$object2 = $object1.Clone() # assumes that $object's type implements ICloneable
```

`[System.Xml.XmlDocument]` is a [*reference type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types) (as opposed to a [*value type*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types) such as `[int]`), which means that:

```
$object2 = $object1
```

simply makes `$object2` reference (point to) the very same object as `$object1`.

You can verify this as follows:

```sh
[object]::ReferenceEquals($object1, $object2)
```

Generally:

- **`=` with a *value type*** instance creates a **copy of the *actual value***, i.e., it implicitly clones.
- **`=` with a *reference type*** instance creates a **copy of the *reference*** to the instance, i.e., it creates another reference to the very same object.
- The **same applies when you *add elements* to a (mutable) *collection***; e.g. (assume having created a list with `$list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]] @()`):

  - `$var = 42; $list.Add($var)` adds a *copy* of the *value-type* (`[int]`) instance to the list.
  - `$var = [pscustomobject] @{ foo = 'bar' }; $list.Add($var)` adds a *reference* to the *reference-type* (`[pscustomobject]`) instance to the list.

To **determine if a given type is a value type or a reference type**, use the type's Boolean **[`.IsValueType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Type.IsValueType)** property:

```
# Inspect a type directly.
PS> [System.Xml.XmlDocument].IsValueType
False    # -> a *reference* type

# Inspect a type via an instance thereof:
PS> $xml = [xml] '<xml/>'; $xml.GetType().IsValueType
False
```