# PowerShell create array failed in a loop

Tags: powershell

Thought I have read enough examples here and elsewhere. Still I fail creating arrays in Power Shell.

With that code I hoped to create slices of pair values from an array.

```
    $values = @('hello','world','bonjour','moon','ola','mars')

function slice_array {
    param (
        [String[]]$Items
    )
    [int16] $size = 2
    $pair = [string[]]::new($size)     # size is 2
    $returns = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    
    [int16] $_i = 0
    foreach($item in $Items){
        $pair[$_i] = $Item
        $_i++;
        if($_i -gt $size - 1){
            $_i = 0
            [void]$returns.Add($pair)
        }
    }
    return $returns
}

slice_array($values)
```

the output is

```
ola
mars
ola
mars
ola
mars
```

I would hope for

```
'hello','world'
'bonjour','moon'
'ola','mars'
```

Is possible to slice that array to an array of arrays with length 2 ?

Any explenation why it doesn't work as expected ?
How should the code be changed ?

Thanks for any hint to properly understand Arrays in PowerShell !

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.  
If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.  
To prevent accidental use of method syntax, use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher, but note its other effects. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a **PowerShell-idiomatic solution** (the fix required for your code is in the bottom section):

- The function is named `Get-Slices` to adhere to PowerShell's verb-noun naming convention (see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands) for more information).

  - Note: Often, the *singular* form of the noun is used, e.g. `Get-Item` rather than `Get-Items`, given that you situationally may get *one* or multiple output values; however, since the express purpose here is to slice a *single* object into *multiple parts*, I've chosen the plural.
- The slice size (count of elements per slice) is passed as a parameter.
- The function uses `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-), to extract a single slice from an array.
- It uses PowerShell's *implicit output behavior* (no need for `return`, no need to build up a list of return values explicitly; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) for more information).
- It shows how to output an array *as a whole* from a function, which requires wrapping it in an auxiliary single-element array using the unary form of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-). Without this auxiliary array, the array's elements would be output *individually* to the pipeline (which is also used for function / script output; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62489498/45375) for more information.

```
# Note: For brevity, argument validation, pipeline support, error handling, ...
#       have been omitted.
function Get-Slices {
  
  param (
    [String[]] $Items
    ,
    [int] $Size   # The slice size (element count)
  )

  $sliceCount = [Math]::Ceiling($Items.Count / $Size)
  if ($sliceCount -le 1) {
    # array is empty or as large as or smaller than a slice? -> 
    # wrap it *twice* to ensure that the output is *always* an 
    # *array of arrays*, in this case containing just *one* element
    # containing the original array.
    ,, $Items
  }
  else {
    foreach ($offset in 0..($sliceCount-1)) {
      , $Items[($offset * $Size)..(($offset+1) * $Size - 1)] # output this slice
    }
  }

}
```

To slice an array into pairs and collect the output in an array of arrays (jagged array):

```
$arrayOfPairs = 
  Get-Slices -Items 'hello','world','bonjour','moon','ola','mars' -Size 2
```

Note:

- *Shell*-like syntax is required when you call functions (commands in general) in PowerShell: arguments are *whitespace-separated* and *not* enclosed in `(...)` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information)
- Since a function's declared parameters are *positional* by default, *naming* the arguments as I've done above (`-Item ...`, `-Size ...`) isn't strictly necessary, but helps readability.

Two sample calls:

```
"`n-- Get pairs (slice count 2):"

Get-Slices -Items 'hello','world','bonjour','moon','ola','mars' -Size 2 |
  ForEach-Object { $_ -join ', ' }


"`n-- Get slices of 3:"

Get-Slices -Items 'hello','world','bonjour','moon','ola','mars' -Size 3 |
  ForEach-Object { $_ -join ', ' }
```

The above yields:

```
-- Get pairs (slice count 2):
hello, world
bonjour, moon
ola, mars

-- Get slices of 3:
hello, world, bonjour
moon, ola, mars
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

The only problem with your code was that **you kept *reusing* the very same auxiliary array for collecting a pair of elements**, so that subsequent iterations replaced the elements of the previous ones, so that, **in the end, your array list contained multiple references to the *same* pair array, reflecting the *last pair only***.

This behavior occurs, because arrays are instance of *reference types* rather than *value types* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45071111/45375) for background information.

The **simplest solution** is to **add a (shallow) *clone* of your `$pair` array to your list**, which ensures that each list entry is a distinct array:

```
[void]$returns.Add($pair.Clone())
```

Answer (score 1):

**Why you got 3 equal pairs instead of different pairs:**

.Net (powershell based on it) is object-oriented language and it has consept of `reference types` and `value types`. Almost all types are `reference types`.

What happens in your code:

1. You create `$pair = [string[]]` object. `$pair` variable actually stores memory address of (*reference to*) `[string[]]` object, because arrays are **reference types**
2. You fill `$pair` array with values
3. You add **(!)** `$pair` to `$returns`. Remember that `$pair` is **reference to memory block**. And when you add it to `$returns`, it adds memory address of `[string[]]` you wrote values to.
4. You repeat step2: You fill `$pair` array with **different** values, but address of this array in memory keeps the same. Doing this you actually replace values from step2 with new  values in the same `$pair` object.
5. = // = step3
6. = // = step4
7. = // = step3

As a result: in `$returns` there are three same memory addresses: `[[reference to $pair], [reference to $pair], [reference to $pair]]`. And `$pair` values were overwritten by code with last pair values.

On output it works like this:

1. Powershell looks at `$results` which is array.
2. Powershell looks to $results[0] which `reference to $pair`
3. Powershell outputs `reference to $pair`[0]
4. Powershell outputs `reference to $pair`[1]
5. Powershell looks to $results[1] which `reference to $pair`
6. Powershell outputs `reference to $pair`[0]
7. Powershell outputs `reference to $pair`[1]
8. Powershell looks to $results[1] which `reference to $pair`
9. Powershell outputs `reference to $pair`[0]
10. Powershell outputs `reference to $pair`[1]

So you see, you triple output the object from the same memory address. You overwritten it 3 times in `slice_array` and now it stores only last pair values.

To fix it in your code, you should create a new `$pair` in memory: add `$pair = [string[]]::new($size)` just after `$returns.Add($pair)`

Comment: I appreciate your fight to help here !

Comment: your code last comment works like charm on strings but how would I do the same on a list createtd by $_content = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($file_path)